# How to Add missing items into JavaScript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have following JavaScript array:

```
[
    {
        "day": 0,
        "best_hour_of_the_day": "10",
        "appt_success_rate": "60",
        "appt_100_numbers": "27"
    },
    {
        "day": 2,
        "best_hour_of_the_day": "10",
        "appt_success_rate": "60",
        "appt_100_numbers": "27"
    },
    {
        "day": 3,
        "best_hour_of_the_day": "10",
        "appt_success_rate": "60",
        "appt_100_numbers": "27"
    },
    {
        "day": 4,
        "best_hour_of_the_day": "10",
        "appt_success_rate": "60",
        "appt_100_numbers": "27"
    },
    {
        "day": 6,
        "best_hour_of_the_day": "--",
        "appt_success_rate": "0",
        "appt_100_numbers": "0"
    }
]
```

And I have defined array with with representation of the days which i need in result.

```
var daysOfTheWeek = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6];
```

I would like to ask, what is the good way how to add missing items to JavaScript array?

It means add missing values 1 and 6 to get following JavaScript result:

```
[
    {
        "day": 0,
        "best_hour_of_the_day": "10",
        "appt_success_rate": "60",
        "appt_100_numbers": "27"
    },
    {
        "day": 1,
        "best_hour_of_the_day": "--",
        "appt_success_rate": "0",
        "appt_100_numbers": "0"
    },
    {
        "day": 2,
        "best_hour_of_the_day": "10",
        "appt_success_rate": "60",
        "appt_100_numbers": "27"
    },
    {
        "day": 3,
        "best_hour_of_the_day": "10",
        "appt_success_rate": "60",
        "appt_100_numbers": "27"
    },
    {
        "day": 4,
        "best_hour_of_the_day": "10",
        "appt_success_rate": "60",
        "appt_100_numbers": "27"
    },
    {
        "day": 5,
        "best_hour_of_the_day": "10",
        "appt_success_rate": "60",
        "appt_100_numbers": "27"
    },
    {
        "day": 6,
        "best_hour_of_the_day": "--",
        "appt_success_rate": "0",
        "appt_100_numbers": "0"
    }
]
```

Comment: You are missing a language tag!

Comment: I assume it's `javascript`

Comment: The finally commas after the entries for `day: 5` in the first example and after `day: 6` in the second example are **not** valid syntax.

Comment: Use JSONLint to check your syntax: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: I just updated syntax to JSON. But principle should be relative same for JS and JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I am giving the solution in *JAVASCRIPT* :**

**see demo:**

**jsfiddle link:** http://jsfiddle.net/3phba87q/

**given:**

```
var dummyData=[
        {
            day: 0,
            best_hour_of_the_day: "10",
            appt_success_rate: "60",
            appt_100_numbers: "27"
        },
        {
            day: 2,
            best_hour_of_the_day: "10",
            appt_success_rate: "60",
            appt_100_numbers: "27"
        },
        {
            day: 3,
            best_hour_of_the_day: "10",
            appt_success_rate: "60",
            appt_100_numbers: "27"
        },
        {
            day: 4,
            best_hour_of_the_day: "10",
            appt_success_rate: "60",
            appt_100_numbers: "27"
        },
        {
            day: 5,
            best_hour_of_the_day: "10",
            appt_success_rate: "60",
            appt_100_numbers: "27"
        }
    ];
var daysOfTheWeek = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6];
```

**in order to get expected result:**

```
var existingDays = [];
// get the existing days

for(var i=0;i<dummyData.length;i++){
    existingDays[i] = dummyData[i]['day'];
}

// check which day's data is missing; then create a dummy object and push it to the dummyData object

for(var i=0;i<daysOfTheWeek.length;i++){
   if(existingDays.indexOf(parseInt(daysOfTheWeek[i])) < 0){
       var dummyObject = {
        "day": i,
        "best_hour_of_the_day": "--",
        "appt_success_rate": "0",
        "appt_100_numbers": "0"
       };
       dummyData.push(dummyObject);
   }
}

//sort day wise ascending

dummyData.sort(function(x,y){ return parseInt(x.day) - parseInt(y.day) });
```

Answer (score 2):

In modern JS, this would be

```
function addMissingItems(days, input) {

  function get (day) { return find(day) || make(day); }
  function find(day) { return input.find(function(x) { return x.day===day; }); }
  function make(day) { return { day: day, ...}; }

  return days.map(get);
}

var newArray = addMissingItems(daysOfTheWeek, input);
```

This uses `map` to create and return an array parallel to `daysOfTheWeek`, where each element is the result of calling `get`. `get` tries to find an element in the input for that day, by calling `find`, and if that doesn't work, creates a new element for that day, by calling `make`.

This uses `Array#find`, which may or may not be available in your browser. There's a polyfill at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find. Or, you could write your own:

```
function findInArray(array, condition) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var elt = array[i];
        if (condition(elt, i, array)) return elt;
    }
}
```

and change the implementation of `find` in the code above to

```
return findInArray(input, function() {...});
```